# How can I extend the parent style in sass?

Tags: css, sass, extend

I want to structure my selectors in a BEM-ish style and have something like:

```
.card {
  color: red;

  &__button {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    &-disabled {
      @extend $;
      background: black;
    }
  }
}
```

And the Result CSS to be like:

```
.card {
  color: red;
}
.card .card__button-disabled, .card .card__button {
  background: gray;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card__button-disabled {
  background: black;
}
```

So I can only use the "card__button-disabled" class name instead of "card__button card__button-disabled".

I can do it like this: (and it works)

```
.card {
  color: red;

  %button {
    background: gray;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  &__button {
    @extend %button;

    &-disabled {
      @extend %button;
      background: black;
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't like the extra abstraction. I hope there is something like:
@extend parent;

Comment: The easiest to read, the better. Code length doesn't always matter.

Comment: Hello, if I understood you, you could also do something like that :
.card {
color: red;
  &__button {
    &, &-disabled {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }
  &__button-disabled {
    background: black;
  }
}

Comment: Yes but I don't like creating the extra selectors. This can hide the behavior and lead to errors or unused - generated css. ... In other words ... it can be better :)